# Построение графика функции в java

Tags: java

ищу способ как в java по заданой формуле, например sin(x) построить график. Пример: [image]

Comment: а что у вас не получилсоь?

Comment: Очевидно, найти способ...

Comment: Предлагаю рассмотреть StdDraw

Comment: Получилось найти способ отрисовки?